# Creating custom fluent API

Tags: java, dsl, fluent

I'm going to create custom fluent API for my application. I decided to check code of already existing libraries and found some monsters in at least 2 projects that using fluent api.

I saw that there're many classes and interfaces, that differ only in number of generic types.

For example: In jOOQ library [DerivedColumnList22](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/DerivedColumnList22.java)

In RxJava: [Action9](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/functions/Action9.java)

What is the purpose of monsters like this? Is it only for performance cases? Or is it some commonalities and way to go in fluent apis?

It looks scary to implement own DSL in fluent api, when you see monsters like this.

Answer (score 9):

Since you mentioned the [jOOQ library](http://www.jooq.org), I'll give an authoritative answer here, being the author of jOOQ, and having written this post about designing fluent APIs (or rather: designing internal domain specific languages in Java):
https://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course

#### SomeType22 is just a nominal tuple type

What you've discovered is the common desire of API designers to work with tuples. A few languages have built-in support for structural tuple types, i.e. tuple types that can be created in an ad-hoc manner, rather than declaring them in advance and giving them names. The latter is called nominal typing. [More details about nominal/structural typing here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_and_structural_type_systems).

#### Examples of languages with structural tuple type support:

SQL is an excellent example of a language that allows for creating ad-hoc tuple types:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, age
FROM people
```

The above query creates a table of tuples of degree 3 with types `(string, string, number)`. JavaScript is another example, where I can quickly generate a tuple as such:

```javascript
var x = {
    firstName: "Lukas",
    lastName: "Eder",
    age: undefined
};
```

There are other languages that have tuple support to some level. Ideally, tuples allow access by name *and* index to individual attributes. Sometimes, access is given only by name. In other cases, it is only given by index. But it's always the same thing, conceptually.

#### What does it mean for `DerivedColumnList22` and `Action9`

The Java language, unfortunately, has no such tools to create ad-hoc structural tuple types. (Almost) everything in Java needs to be nominally typed. Even "anonymous functions" (lambda expressions) need to be assigned to a nominal SAM type:

```java
    Runnable r = () -> { doSomething(); }
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- Syntactically looks like a structural type
//  ^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------------------ But it's really a nominal type
```

So, if an API wants to give its users the illusion of supporting real structural tuple types, it has to provide names for each supported type in advance. For instance, `Action9`:

```java
Action9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9> action = 
    (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) -> { doSomething(); }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------- Look ma! Almost a structural tuple type!
```

So, this technique is mostly implemented by libraries like RxJava (which encourages functional programming where structural tuple types really shine) or jOOQ (which encourages SQL where structural tuple types also really shine).

Other libraries / APIs include:

- Scala's [`Tuple1` - `Tuple22`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Tuple22.html)
- .NET's [`Tuple1` - `Tuple8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

This doesn't mean that you need those types in your own DSL. Start simple. Eventually, you may feel you need to add them.

Comment: I've always wondered how you decide to stop. Why `Record22` and not `Record21` or `Record23` ? How is this number decided ? Based on some statistics ?

Comment: @Spotted: Based on Scala, whose Tuples reach from [`Tuple1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Tuple1.html) to [`Tuple22`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Tuple22.html). Now why *they* stopped with 22 is a different question :) (Note, in jOOQ, after 22 you just lose typesafety but you can continue with `Record` forever)

Comment: Yep my question was: do you know *why they stopped with 22* ? And more generically, how do you decide when to stop when designing such systems ? Do you start small and when people start complaining you increase or you try to gather some data to compute some usage prediction and design accordingly ?

Comment: I don't think most Scala core people know. Probably some elaborate joke, kind of like half 42 (because 42) and then off-by-one error. When do you stop? Easy. When you've reached "good enough". And as you say, you'll wait until someone complains. In SQL, 22 is not really enough. In functional programming, 8 should usually suffice (see [.NET's tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 2):

In RxJava, those numbered interfaces give lambda-convenience to users who need to work with 2-9 sources/values at the same time. `Action9` is not in use by RxJava proper but its sister `Func9` is available as an argument on `combineLatest` and `zip`. Based on experience from Rx.NET, we thought it is unlikely people will use combine/zip with more than 9 direct sources, plus not having `Func10` avoids member sorting problems when listing them out (i.e., `Func1`, `Func10`, `Func2`).

For more than 9 sources, there is the `FuncN<R>` defined as a functional interface with a a single method `R call(Object... args)` at the cost that you have to manually extract elements and cast them back to their respective types:

```
Observable.zip(Arrays.asList(ints, strings, objects, t4, t5, t6, ...), a -> {
    int p1 = (Integer)a[0];
    String p2 = (String)a[1];
    //...
})
```

Under the hood, the regular `Func2`-`Func9` [are wrapped](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/functions/Functions.java#L79) into a `FuncN` for combineLatest/zip so these operators each can have an any number of sources implementation instead of 9 slightly different one. Then the wrapper just unpacks the array it gets called with like above.